# KeyEvent doesn't understand ENTER key

Tags: java, keyboard, keyevent

I'm creating a notepad using java.there seems to be a small problem.Java doesnt get the line of the code that has a condition concerning ENTER key.It understands ctrl and Alt.but not enter.just skips that part! what can I do?`

```
if( !e.isControlDown() && !e.isAltDown() && e.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
            frame.wholeText.linesList.get(frame.cursor.j).chars.add(frame.cursor.i,c);
            frame.cursor.i += 1 ;
            System.out.println("Entered");
            charMetric = frame.getFontMetrics( frame.getFont() ).charWidth(c) ;
            frame.cursor.setX( frame.cursor.getX() + charMetric );

        }`
```

PS : It should not enter this condition when I press ENTER but it does.
PS2:It is in KeyTyped part of the code.

Comment: Well you are checking is the key code is not enter. Change your if state  to: `if( !e.isControlDown() && !e.isAltDown() && e.getKeyCode().equals(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER))`

Comment: yeah but it enters this condition when I press Enter,whilest it should not

Comment: Maybe try the `equals` operator instead of `!=`

Comment: @SamOrozco, the constants are `int` and `getKeyCode()` returns an `int`, so that shouldn't matter.

Comment: What is the "e" variable Class? KeyEvent?

Comment: Can you output the key code when you get into that statement and see what the value is.

Comment: I'm assuming that the `KeyListener` is attached to something like a `JTextArea`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for KeyEvent.getKeyCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyCode--) is pretty clear:

> **Returns:** the integer code for an actual key on the keyboard. (For KEY_TYPED events, the keyCode is VK_UNDEFINED.)

Conversely, [KeyEvent.getKeyChar()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar--) says:

> KEY_PRESSED and KEY_RELEASED events are not intended for reporting of character input. Therefore, the values returned by this method are guaranteed to be meaningful only for KEY_TYPED events.

KEY_PRESSED and KEY_RELEASED events generate a KeyEvent with a valid keyCode, but no keyChar.  KEY_TYPED events are the opposite:  they generate a KeyEvent with a valid keyChar, but the keyCode is always undefined.

You are checking the value of getKeyCode() for a KEY_TYPED event, so the keyCode will always be undefined.

Either use `e.getKeyChar() != '\n'` or perform your keyCode check in a [keyPressed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html#keyPressed-java.awt.event.KeyEvent-) method.